# OcMock vs OcMockito - what are pros and cons

Tags: ios, xcode, tdd, ocmock, ocmockito

For iOS tdd testing/mocking which framework would you recommend? I heard that OcMock has been around longer and is more lightweight. Could anyone provide a few examples of the pros and cons or demo some strengths of each. I'm just looking for a standard mocking framework that's fast but i'd like to know all the drawbacks/benefits of each.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's already a sort-of-comparison on http://www.objc.io/issue-15/mocking-stubbing.html

It basically boils down to:

> OCMock has a lot more functionality than OCMockito, which, depending on your personal preference, could be a benefit or a drawback.
>
> Both are installable via CocoaPods, so they’re easy to integrate with your existing test setup

*I'm new to iOS testing, so I just leave this here to point anyone into the right direction until someone else provides a more elaborate answer.*

Comment: also I would like to add that [OCMock](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/blob/master/OCMock.podspec) has support for iOS 5.0 and [OCMockito](https://github.com/jonreid/OCMockito/blob/master/OCMockito.podspec) has support for iOS 6.0